# Manipulate in modal mode

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, evaluation, scheduling

It is sometimes convenient to use `Manipulate` to set up global values which are to be used in the rest of the notebook. In such cases one can select and run the notebook up to the cell containing `Manipulate`, use the dynamic interface, and subsequently select and run the remainder of the notebook.

But it would be great to evaluate the whole notebook with the `"Evaluate Notebook"` menu item, and have the evaluation pause after the `Manipulate`, then continue when the user clicks a button indicating that they are done manipulating.

A simple example (each line represents a separate cell):

```
Manipulate[amazingGraphics[y], {y, 0, 1}, Button["Done", global = y^2]]

(* evaluation pauses here until the button is clicked *)

doSomeStuff[global]

doSomeMoreStuff[]

etc[]
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: Can you make up a minimal working example? How would you indicate that a given `Manipulate` is finished?

Comment: @YvesKlett https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hShY6xZWVGE

Comment: @belisarius a classic, closely followed by the formula for [transparent aluminum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_materials#Transparent_aluminum).

Comment: @YvesKlett Yep.I _love_ this sentence: _" However, the transparent state lasted for only 40 femtoseconds, until electrons returned to the material."_

Comment: I think what the OP requests is a bad idea and completely subverts the intended use of dynamic forms such as `Manipulate`, but it might be possible. My idea is to rig some sort of trigger, conditionally evaluated within the first argument expression of the `Manipulate`, that deletes the output cell. I'm a little unclear about the "next cell should be evaluated after `Manipulate` has finished" bit. Not obvious to me which cell qualifies as next :D Joking aside, I say to the OP: you need to tell us much more about what you are trying to accomplish before we can help you.

Comment: I think @LiMa may just want the `ContinuousAction`, `SynchronousUpdating`, and/or `SynchronousInitialization` options.

Comment: I'll take a stab at interpreting the OP's request - I think the desired functionality is to generate a set of controller states, then use a `Button` to store those states in a symbol and execute some further code.

Comment: While the question is incomplete, I think bobthechemist's interpretation is correct and I would find the functionality useful. Hopefully my edit will make the question suitable for reopening.

Answer (score 5):

Taking inspiration from Kuba's answer I went digging in `DialogInput` and found the undocumented function `WaitUntil` which is used to pause evaluation until its argument is `True`. So this works:

```
a = 1;
Column[{
  Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, LocalizeVariables -> False],
  $done = False; DefaultButton[$done = True]
  }]
```

*next cell...*

```
WaitUntil[$done];
a
```

Here's a picture of the notebook before the button is clicked. I used "Evaluate Notebook" from the menu and the evaluation has paused at `WaitUntil`, allowing me to use the `Manipulate` controls to set `a` and then click the button to continue the evaluation:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with `DialogInput` or friends:

```
a = 1;

DialogInput@
 Column[{Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, 
    LocalizeVariables -> False], DefaultButton[]}]

a
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good idea, though it would be nice to keep the Manipulate in the notebook.

Comment: @SimonWoods I'd say it's a matter of taste :)

Comment: Agreed, sometimes the dialog is a better choice.