# Question about WaitUntil

Tags: undocumented, built-in-symbols

I have a such function:

```
fun := DynamicModule[{from, 
   to}, {FileNameSetter[Dynamic[from], "Directory", 
     Appearance -> "from where"], 
    FileNameSetter[Dynamic[to], "Directory", Appearance -> "to where"]}
   WaitUntil[And @@ {ValueQ[from], ValueQ[to]}];
  Print[StringJoin[from, to]]]
```

I mean,When I run the `fun`,I want to print that folder string after I select that two folder,but why this code cannot work?Any bug in my code?Or how to implement it?

Comment: Re update: probably because: [Working with DynamicModule: SetDelayed + OwnValues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121584/5478), not to mention that you are multiplying WaitUntil with Dynamic@Grid.

Comment: p.s. what about putting  a Button to `Print` instead of using undocumented feature.

Comment: @Kuba The `Print` is other something in my real qeustion.And I have tried your `Button`,it [work too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH18S.png),but I want to make this two part in a custom function.Do you think it is feasible?And I should provide all code?

Comment: Why do you insist on WaitUntil if you don't know how it works. There are documented ways to control flow. Maybe DialogInput would be apropriate?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for your suggestion.As your promption,`SystemDialogInput["Directory"]` solve my question almost.but I will wait a solution with a `WaitUntil` in this post. :)

Comment: I think you have asked the wrong question here. I have posted a question that I think is the one you really want answered. Take a look at it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134104/3066)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any bug in your code? I would say: yes, the bug of using undocumented functions without taking the time to figure what they do. Now I don't know much about `WaitUntil`, but by reading [Simon Woods answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101443/3066), I got the idea the following might work:

```
Clear[done, from, to]
done := And @@ {ValueQ[from], ValueQ[to]}

Dynamic @
  Row[
    {FileNameSetter[Dynamic[from], "Directory", Appearance -> "from where"], 
     FileNameSetter[Dynamic[to], "Directory", Appearance -> "to where"]} ]

 WaitUntil[done]; Print[from, "  ", to]
```

And it does. This is what cell group looks like when it is initially evaluated.

[image: initial]

And this is what it looks like after both directories have be chosen.

[image: final]

Comment: I mean,I want to make it a module pack,but it don't work still?

Comment: @yode. Think about what this shows -- that the two file name setters and the `WaitUntil` expression all have to be active at the same time. Your code must accomplish that. So that's what you need to concentrate on